# searchd.service failed: never wrote its PID file. Failing Error

Tags: apache2, systemd

I have been trying to sort out the sphinx issue but still havent been able to fix it. I would appreciate some help. I tried sorting it out with some help online but it hasn't helped me fix this issue.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start searchd
Job for searchd.service failed because a configured resource limit was 
exceeded. See "systemctl status searchd.service and "journalctl -xe" for 
details.
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ systemctl status searchd.service -l
● searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2017-07-26 11:50:29 BST; 20s ago
Process: 10735 ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10732 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10730 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ udo systemctl status searchd -l
-bash: udo: command not found
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status searchd -l
● searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2017-07-26 11:50:29 BST; 48s ago
Process: 10735 ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10732 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10730 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain searchd[10735]: [258B blob data]
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain searchd[10735]: [218B blob data]
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain searchd[10735]: [223B blob data]
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain searchd[10735]: Copyright (c) 2001-
2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain searchd[10735]: Copyright (c) 2008-
 2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://srch.com)
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from 
file /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid: Invalid arguement
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: searchd.service never 
wrote its PID file. Failing.
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start SphinxSearch Search Engine.
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit searchd.service entered failed state.
Jul 26 11:50:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: searchd.service failed.
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rm /var/run/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid’: No such file or directory
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -ogp /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 6 Mar  1 02:14 /var/run -> ../run/
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -ogp /var/run/
total 44
-rw-r--r--.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 auditd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:22 blkid/
-rw-r--r--.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 chronyd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 console/
-rw-r--r--.  1    5 Jul 25 14:22 crond.pid
----------.  1    0 Jul 25 14:17 cron.reboot
drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 25 14:17 dbus/
-rw-r--r--.  1    4 Jul 26 09:40 dhclient-eth0.pid
prw-------.  1    0 Jul 25 14:17 dmeventd-client
prw-------.  1    0 Jul 25 14:17 dmeventd-server
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 faillock/
-rw-------.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 gssproxy.pid
srw-rw-rw-.  1    0 Jul 25 14:17 gssproxy.sock
drwx--x---.  3  100 Jul 25 17:31 httpd/
drwxr-xr-x.  4  120 Jul 25 14:17 initramfs/
drwxr-xr-x.  6  140 Jul 26 03:19 lock/
drwxr-xr-x.  3   60 Jul 25 14:17 log/
drwx------.  2   80 Jul 25 14:17 lvm/
-rw-r--r--.  1    5 Jul 25 14:23 lvmetad.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 25 14:17 mount/
drwxrwxr-x.  2   40 Apr 12 21:24 netreport/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   80 Jul 25 14:17 NetworkManager/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 plymouth/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 ppp/
drwx------.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 rpcbind/
srw-rw-rw-.  1    0 Jul 25 14:22 rpcbind.sock
drwxrwxr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 screen/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 sepermit/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   40 Jul 25 14:17 setrans/
drwx--x--x.  2   60 Jul 25 17:31 setroubleshoot/
-rw-------.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 sm-notify.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 26 11:50 sphinx/
-rw-r--r--.  1    5 Jul 25 14:23 sshd.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 25 14:17 sysconfig/
-rw-------.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 syslogd.pid
drwxr-xr-x. 17  420 Jul 26 11:50 systemd/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 25 14:17 tmpfiles.d/
drwxr-xr-x.  2   60 Jul 25 14:23 tuned/
drwxr-xr-x.  7  160 Jul 25 14:23 udev/
drwxr-xr-x.  3   60 Jul 26 11:50 user/
-rw-rw-r--.  1 1536 Jul 26 11:50 utmp
-rw-r-----.  1    4 Jul 25 14:17 vboxadd-service.sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rm /var/run/sphinx/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/sphinx/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid’: No such file or directory
 [vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -la /var/run/
 total 44
 drwxr-xr-x. 28 root           root            880 Jul 25 17:28 .
 dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root           root            239 Mar 24 17:00 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 auditd.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:22 blkid
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 chronyd.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 console
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jul 25 14:22 crond.pid
 ----------.  1 root           root              0 Jul 25 14:17 cron.reboot
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:17 dbus
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jul 26 09:40 dhclient-
  eth0.pid
 prw-------.  1 root           root              0 Jul 25 14:17 dmeventd-
 client
 prw-------.  1 root           root              0 Jul 25 14:17 dmeventd-
 server
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 faillock
 -rw-------.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 gssproxy.pid
 srw-rw-rw-.  1 root           root              0 Jul 25 14:17 
 gssproxy.sock
 drwx--x---.  3 root           apache          100 Jul 25 17:31 httpd
 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root           root            120 Jul 25 14:17 initramfs
 drwxr-xr-x.  6 root           root            140 Jul 26 03:19 lock
 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:17 log
 drwx------.  2 root           root             80 Jul 25 14:17 lvm
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jul 25 14:23 lvmetad.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:17 mount
 drwxrwxr-x.  2 root           root             40 Apr 12 21:24 netreport
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             80 Jul 25 14:17 
 NetworkManager
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 plymouth
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 ppp
 drwx------.  2 rpc            rpc              40 Jul 25 14:17 rpcbind
 srw-rw-rw-.  1 root           root              0 Jul 25 14:22 rpcbind.sock
 drwxrwxr-x.  2 root           screen           40 Jul 25 14:17 screen
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 sepermit
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jul 25 14:17 setrans
 drwx--x--x.  2 setroubleshoot setroubleshoot   60 Jul 25 17:31 
 setroubleshoot
 -rw-------.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 sm-
 notify.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 sphinx         sphinx           60 Jul 26 11:50 sphinx
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jul 25 14:23 sshd.pid
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:17 sysconfig
 -rw-------.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 syslogd.pid
  drwxr-xr-x. 17 root           root            420 Jul 26 11:50 systemd
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:17 tmpfiles.d
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jul 25 14:23 tuned
  drwxr-xr-x.  7 root           root            160 Jul 25 14:23 udev
  drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           root             60 Jul 26 11:50 user
  -rw-rw-r--.  1 root           utmp           1536 Jul 26 11:50 utmp
  -rw-r-----.  1 root           root              4 Jul 25 14:17 vboxadd-
  service.sh
  [vagrant@localhost ~]$ less /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch
  /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch: No such file or directory
  [vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

I would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: What exactly is "the sphinx issue" and what is your question?

Comment: The issue is that sphinx.search is not starting. when I check the status it says: Active: Failed.
Searchd.service never wrote its PID file. Failed.
Unit searchd.service entered in failed state.
Failed to read PID file from  file /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid : invalid arguement

Comment: It is `disabled`. Have you tried `enable`-ing it?

Comment: Thank you... 
I enabled it and still I am getting the error: Active: Failed. Failed. Unit searchd.service entered in failed state. Failed to read PID file from file /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid : invalid arguement

Comment: Try manually creating a `.pid` file with `sudo touch /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid`.

Comment: I did that yesterday and it does create file but then still for some reason it doesn't read the file and it's the same error over and over again. 
I tried again and checked, it doesn't recognise it, still getting the same errors as above. 
I restarted searchd.service but didn't help.

Comment: What is the location of the `.pid` file, as specified in the `.config` file?

Comment: This is the pid_file: /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
acc. to config file.

Comment: If it's called `/var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid` why are you trying to remove `/var/run/sphinx/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid`. Check the folder more careful. `ls -l /var/run/sphinx/`

Comment: Yes, in that folder there is search.pid file with this permission: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jul 25 17:48 search.pid
If it is then why is is saying invalid argument with failed to read PID file from /var/run/sphinx/search.pid